# Stick USB modem to specific /dev/ link

Tags: linux, usb-modem

I have up to 4 USB GSM modems from different providers. When I plug it,`udev/usbmodeswitch` makes a symlink to each device at `/dev/gsmmodem`, `/dev/gsmmodem2` and so on.

I need to make the symlink name for each modem to be permanent. So if I plug `modem3` it always symlinks to /dev/gsmmodem3, even when there is no other modems attached.

I've tried create `udev` rule for this but these do not seem to work:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1506", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB%n", SYMLINK="gsmmodem1_%n"

ATTRS{idVendor}=="1410", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6000", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB%n", SYMLINK="gsmmodem2_%n"
```

How do I build a correct `udev` rule or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: for now, best way I've found - use usb_modeswitch's symlinks in `/dev/serial/by-id/`